# How do I ShowDialog based on MessageBox selection

Tags: c#, .net, forms, dialog, modal-dialog

I am using C# here.  I have a form where the user can select Yes or No, and if they choose No, a message box appears and asks them if they are sure.  If they click No, I want to show the form again.  Here's my code:

```
public void function()
{
    MyForm form = new MyForm();
    if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?",
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            runFinished.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            //Show form again. How??
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks everybody for your help!

Comment: How many times do you want to ask them? Until they click "Yes" or a set number of times?

Comment: can't you just call form.ShowDialog() again....?

Comment: I want to keep showing until they click yes on MyForm or No on the message box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrange that the `No` button `MyForm` does the call to `MessageBox`. Only if the user is sure do you then go on to close the dialog.  Your current approach of asking the question after the dialog has closed is incorrect.

You can effect the change by making sure that `DialogResult` is set in code rather than by the No button's `DialogResult` property.  Then in the click handler for the button you run the message box. If the user confirms the action, then set the forms `DialogResult` to `DialogResult.No`.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the whole property thing in C#. I always forget that I can change them programatically _and_ using the drop-down menus.

Comment: One more question.  My understanding is that if the user clicks on the X to close my `MyForm`, then the return value of `ShowDialog()` is `DialogResult.Cancel`.  Is there a way to handle that without closing the form?

Answer (score 2):

Call two events depending on whether no or yes is selected (within MyForm).  For example

```
void OnNoEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
      this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
      this.Close();
   }
}

void OnYesEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
   this.Close();
}
```

This is probably better than opening the dialog box many times.

Then the code to open the dialog is easy.

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
   // perform actions here
```

Comment: The calls to `this.Close()` are not necessary in a modal dialog.

Comment: Hmm interesting.  I didn't know, thanks.  You answered in a similar manner before I did anyways.  Kudos

Comment: Thanks for the help. David beat you to it, so I've selected his answer, but I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

There is the standart means: [Form.FormClosing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing.aspx).

See example: [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something here, but why not use a while loop?

```
public void function()
{
    MyForm form = new MyForm();

    while(form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.No)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?",
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            runFinished.Dispose();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```